# DLList: my function doesn't produce expected output

Tags: java

For a data structure course, I created an DLList program based on this [DLList Tutorial](https://www.java2novice.com/data-structures-in-java/linked-list/doubly-linked-list/). I made two functions `displayWithForLoop()` and `display()`. I was expected them to produce the same output but they didn't. Why is that?

```
public class DLList<E> {
    Node dummy, head, tail;
    int size;

    public DLList() {
        size = 0;
    }

    class Node {
        E element;
        Node next;
        Node prev;

        public Node(E element, Node next, Node prev) {
            this.element = element;
            this.next = next;
            this.prev = prev;
        }
    }

    public void pushNode(E item) {
        Node newNode = newNode(item, head, dummy);
        if(head != null) head.prev = newNode;
        head = newNode;

        if(tail == null) = newNode;
        size++;
        System.out.println("pushing: " + element);
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("iterating forward...");
        Node pointer = head;
        while (pointer != null) {
            System.out.println(pointer.element);
            pointer = pointer.next;
        }
    }

    public displayWithForLoop() {
        Node pointer = head;
        for(int i = 0; i < size -1; i++) {
            pointer = pointer.next;
            System.out.println(pointer.element);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DLList<Integer> list = new DLList<Integer>();
        list.pushNode(15);
        list.pushNode(25);
        list.pushNode(35);

        list.displayWithForLoop();
        System.out.println("***");
        list.display();

    }
}
```

My output is:
    `pushing: 15
    pushing: 25
    pushing: 35
    3
    25
    15
    ***
    iterating forward..
    35
    25
    15`

Why is the output for list.displayWithForLoop() different from list.display()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say why the output is different in the way you presented but your `displayWithForLoop` method seems to skip printing the head of the list.
You can swap the order of the two calls within the for loop:

```
public displayWithForLoop() {
    Node pointer = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(pointer.element);
        pointer = pointer.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. oh my gosh I feel so embarrassed. The reason why it was a '3' and and not a '35' was because in my original code I used a function getSize() to get the size of the list which was '3' right before the displayWithForLoop(). Thank you very much for your help, kind sir.